# Custom Objects Listbox Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of postcodeitems and I bind this to a listbox.
It contains two properties : postcode, area.

I want to loop through the listbox items and if the item is selected, add the postcodeitem object to another list.

```
            List<Valueobjects.postcodeitem> temp = _BL.GetPostCodeAreasFromZones();
            PCList.AddRange(temp);
            ListBox1.DataSource = PCList;
            ListBox1.DataBind();


List<Valueobjects.postcodeitem> postcodecollection = new List<Valueobjects.postcodeitem>();

foreach (ListItem listitem in ListBox1.Items)
{
    if (listitem.Selected)
    {
        i = i + 1;

        //Run at 20 to speed up query
        if (i == 20)
        {
            //Get data
            CustList.AddRange(BL.SearchCustomerByPostcodeArea(postcodecollection,2));
            i = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //add the post code to temp list
                postcodecollection.Add(listitem);
            }
        }
    }

    if (i > 0)
    {
        //get data
        CustList.AddRange(BL.SearchCustomerByPostcodeArea(postcodecollection,2));
    }
}
```

Obviously where I am trying to add (listitem) isnt going to work as this is a list item and not a postcodeitem. My question is how do I get the postcodeitem object within the list where the list item is selected?

thanks

Comment: Next time you ask a question, be so kind to format your question. It was very hard to read. The better your question is formatted, the more answers you'll get, keep that in mind.

Comment: Can you post the code where you bind ListBox1.Items to a data source?

Comment: It could be as simple as this: postcodecollection.Add((Valueobjects.postcodeitem)listitem);

Comment: Thanks I have added where I bind to the list. Silly question but how do I format my code. Sorry

Comment: Also tried your suggestion however I am getting error : Error 13 Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'GeoLocation.Classes.Valueobjects.postcodeitem

Answer (score 1):

Try something like following.

```
IList<Employee> boundList = ListBox1.DataSource
var obj = boundList[ListBox1.SelectedIndex]
```

**Update** => I have not tested the code but something like following. Using for loop to track the element index.

```
for (int i = 0; i< ListBox1.Items.Length; i++)
{
    if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        i = i + 1;

        //Run at 20 to speed up query
        if (i == 20)
        {
            //Get data
            CustList.AddRange(BL.SearchCustomerByPostcodeArea(postcodecollection,2));
            i = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //add the post code to temp list
                postcodecollection.Add(ListBox1.DataSource.ToList().ElementAt(i));
            }
        }
    }

    if (i > 0)
    {
        //get data
        CustList.AddRange(BL.SearchCustomerByPostcodeArea(postcodecollection,2));
    }
}
```

Anyways this is not recommended way. You should get selected value and use that selected value(unique field) to fetch relevant data from any persistant storage like database.

Comment: Thanks however I am getting error : Error 13 Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'GeoLocation.Classes.Valueobjects.postcodeitem'